# Error on Simple SQL Update Statement

Tags: sql

I have a simple update statement but I am getting an error on the second SET statement:  expecting ',', id, pseudocode or variable.  I can't see what I am doing wrong.  Please help.

```
update DLprc
   set salesamt = q.salesamt, 
   set salestx = q.salestx,          <<<---- error line
   set nsales = q.nsales
from DLprc a
inner join q on a.customer = q.customer
```

Comment: just remove the 2nd and 3rd `SET`

Comment: @Missy Remove the keyword `SET` from the query. Leave everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to repeat `SET`:

```
update DLprc
   set salesamt = q.salesamt, 
       salestx = q.salestx,          
       nsales = q.nsales
from DLprc a
inner join q on a.customer = q.customer
```

I'm accustomed to the following format for `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`:

```
update a
   set a.salesamt = q.salesamt, 
       a.salestx = q.salestx,          
       a.nsales = q.nsales
from DLprc a
inner join q on a.customer = q.customer
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error. You'll have to remove some keywords:

```
update DLprc
   set salesamt = q.salesamt,
       salestx = q.salestx,
       nsales = q.nsales
from DLprc a
inner join q on a.customer = q.customer /* You can add more predicates here, too! */
```

The keyword is always used once, even if there's multiple predicates (conditions). You can add more statements to any one keyword.

In order to find the cause of syntax errors, I look at how others do their syntax.

Comment: Your updated query is correct, but why do you still say "You'll have to use individual statements"?